# Pig JsonLoader issue - is not parsing custom json correctly

Tags: mapreduce, apache-pig

I am new to pig and am trying to parse a json with the following structure

```
{"id1":197,"id2":[ 
    {"id3":"109.11.11.0","id4":"","id5":1391233948301},
    {"id3":"10.10.15.81","id4":"","id5":1313393100648},
    ...
]}
```

The above file is called jsonfile.txt

```
alias = load 'jsonfile.txt' using JsonLoader('id1:int,id2:[id3:chararray,id4:chararray,id5:chararray]');
```

This is the error I get.

ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200:   mismatched input 'id3' expecting RIGHT_BRACKET

Do you know what i could be doing wrong?

Comment: Try checking whole JSON [here](http://jsonlint.com/). Maybe, it is just last trailing comma.

Comment: I just checked the json has a correct format.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON schema is not well formatted.

The formats for complex data types are shown here:

> ```
> Tuple: enclosed by (), items separated by ","
>     Non-empty tuple: (item1,item2,item3)
>     Empty tuple is valid: ()
> Bag: enclosed by {}, tuples separated by ","
>     Non-empty bag: {code}{(tuple1),(tuple2),(tuple3)}{code}
>     Empty bag is valid: {}
> Map: enclosed by [], items separated by ",", key and value separated by "#"
>     Non-empty map: [key1#value1,key2#value2]
>     Empty map is valid: []
> ```

Source : http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/func.html#jsonloadstore

In other words, [] aren't arrays, they're associative tables (maps) where the key character is "#" to split keys and values. Try using tuples (parenthesis) instead.

```
'id1:int,id2:(id3:chararray,id4:chararray,id5:chararray)'
```

OR

```
'id1:int,id2:{(id3:chararray,id4:chararray,id5:chararray)}'
```

I couldn't test it and never trying Pig but according to documentation, it should work just fine.

(based on the following example)

```
a = load 'a.json' using JsonLoader('a0:int,a1:{(a10:int,a11:chararray)},a2:(a20:double,a21:bytearray),a3:[chararray]');
```